# Can not exit/break if else statement

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

My if else statement not breaking when an item has insufficient quantity. It display it has insufficient quantity but still continue and as a result its quantity becomes negative.

For example. Product A has a quantity of 20 in database. In point of sales i tried selling 25. It display "insufficient quantity" but still substract the quantity so the quantity becomes -5. i want it to stop when it says "insufficient quantity".

This is my code

```
   private void btnAddcart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (!validateProduct())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMyDialogBox();
        }
        if (!alreadyincart())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            int str, qty;
            str = Convert.ToInt32(storeqty.Text);
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
            temporaryquantity.Text = str.ToString();

            if (str < qty || str == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Stock", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                //its supposed to stop here but its still subtracting the 
                // quantity from the product
            }
            else
            {
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
                unitprice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                totalprice = qty * unitprice;
                unittotal.Text = totalprice.ToString("0.00");

                addData
                    (
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), //prod id
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), //brand
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), //dosage
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), //qty
                    quantity.Text,
                    unittotal.Text,
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
                    dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
                    );
            }

            int dgvPOSquantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            int dgvnewquantity;
            dgvnewquantity = dgvPOSquantity - qty;
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = dgvnewquantity;

            discountremoveitem();

        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no loop in the coded you posted. Also if it returns an error then explain what error

Comment: As others have noted, you need to show us the loop so we can see how to break out. Checking the obvious:  have you tried a `break;` statement at the point you want to break out?

Comment: What do you mean the *if else statement not breaking*? If goes into the if or the else but not both depending on the conditions

Comment: @GiladGreen i am sorry i mean if else statement. editted it thank you

Comment: _but still continue_ continue how? which statement gets executed and what are you expecting? and can you add the error to the question?

Comment: @FutureDev What is the `error`??

Comment: I updated the code and included a comment there sir. For example sir : the qty of the item is 20. and the quantity that will be sold is 25. it should say "insufficient quantity" and stopped. but here it says "insufficient quantity" and still substract the quantity being sold and its quantity becomes -5

Comment: @FutureDev Is this not just simply because you have the code that does that subtraction outside of the initial if statement? Meaning it runs this line `if (str < qty || str == 0)` then matches the criteria and jumps out the if statement, hitting the next line `int dgvPOSquantity` which does the subtraction.  Move your subtraction code into the else statement?

Comment: If you want it to stop, use `return` in your if statement. Because you have logic outside if, else blocks, what runs after them.

Comment: @Hexie. Thank you! that solved my problem. i wish i could mark your comment as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because you have logic outside the `If` statement.

Meaning it runs this line -

`if (str < qty || str == 0)`

Then matches the criteria and jumps out the `if` statement, hitting the next line

`int dgvPOSquantity`

Which does the subtraction.

Move your subtraction code into the else statement or change the logic flow.

For example:

```
if (str < qty || str == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Stock", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
//This statement is getting hit and exits the IF Statement
        }
        else
        {
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
            unitprice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            totalprice = qty * unitprice;
            unittotal.Text = totalprice.ToString("0.00");

            addData
                (
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), //prod id
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), //brand
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), //dosage
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), //qty
                quantity.Text,
                unittotal.Text,
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
                dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
                );
        }

//But then carries on from here, which does the subtraction. 
//You need to either move this code snippet into the else statement, or change the flow.

        int dgvPOSquantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        int dgvnewquantity;
        dgvnewquantity = dgvPOSquantity - qty;
        dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = dgvnewquantity;

        discountremoveitem();

    }
```